# $G$ be a finite simple group and $H,K$ be subgroups of prime index ; then is it true that $H,K$ are of same size?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

Let $G$ be a finite simple group and $H,K$ be subgroups of prime index ; then is it true that $|H|=|K|$ ?

Comment: What've you tried so far?

Comment: @Arpit Kansal : Nothing much , I feel that the assertion is true but cannot make any headway

Comment: Why do you expect it to be true?

Comment: @Stefan $A_6$ doesn't have any subgroups of prime index.

Comment: I think the answer is yes. A nonabelian simple permutation group of prime degree is doubly transitive (that was proved before the classification), so if $|H| \ne |K|$, then $G$ has two doubly transitive permutation representations of different prime degrees, and there are no such groups. Of course that uses the classification of doubly transitive groups, which uses the classification of finite simple groups. So it would be hard to answer this question without using the classification.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Yes, my comment was very wrong!

Comment: I have answered the question in my comment, so what more do you want to know? The answer to your question is certainly yes,but the argument I gave uses the classification of finite simple groups. It is possible that it could be proved without using the classification, but I would be very surprised if there is an easy or elementary proof.

Comment: @DerekHolt : yes , I am putting the bounty in fact to see if there is an elementary solution . Thank you for your input

Comment: In fact, if you replace "prime" by "prime-power", then it is still true apart from one exception, due to $PSL(2,7)\cong PSL(3,2)$ (which has subgroups of index $7$ and $8$). 


This follows from 

ROBERT M. GURALNICK, Subgroups of Prime Power Index in a Simple Group, JOURNAL OF ALGEBRA 81, 304-311 (1983).

This in turns depends on the classification of course. Like Derek, I am unaware of a classification-free argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $G$ be simple and assume $G$ has a subgroup of prime index, as stated. Define an action of $G$ on $G/H$ ($|G/H|=p$) and $G/K$ ($|G/K|=q$) as usual where $p$ and $q$ are, as usual, primes.

Then the resultant homomorphism $G\to S_p$ has trivial kernel and thus $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_p$. Similarly, $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_q$. Thus, $|G|$ divides $q!$ and $p!$.

Since $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_p$ and $p$ divides the order of $G$ (NB: $|G|=p|H|$) and since $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_q$ as well and $q$ divides the order of $G$ (NB: $|G|=q|K|$), it must be that $q\le p$ if $q$ divides $|G|$ and thus $|S_p|$ and also $p\le q$ if $p$ divides $|G|$ and thus $|S_q|$, whence $p=q$.

Comment: The last paragraph looked messy so I've cleaned it up. I don't believe I changed the essential argument. At least, I hope I haven't.

Comment: I don't understand that why must $q \le p$ if $q|p!$ and $q<p!$ ? ( $q$ is actually less than $|S_p|$ because $G$ is isomorphic to a proper subgroup of $S_p$ since $G$ is simple )

Comment: Sorry I was wrong on saying there was no elementary proof. This is a correct elementary proof, so you should accept it! If $p \ne q$ and, say $p<q$, then $q$ does not divide $p!$, which contradicts the fact that $G$ is a subgroup of $S_p$ of order divisible by $q$.

Comment: @SaunDev Do you get it? Derek's explanation hits the nail on the head. I'll only add that it helps to write out $n!=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots2\cdot1$ for $p$ and $q$ to help see this.